# LINQ equal instead of Contains

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to use equal instead of Contains.
I have an array of codes called selectedDeviceTypeIDs i assume it has two codes {1,2}

I need get result from the query if Devices ids are exactly {1,2} so i have replace selectedDeviceTypeIDs.Contains with selectedDeviceTypeIDs.equal or something like that ...

```
m => m.Devices.Any(w => selectedDeviceTypeIDs.Contains(w.DeviceTypeID)

if (DeviceTypeIDs != null)
{
    Guid[] selectedDeviceTypeIDs = DeviceTypeIDs.Split(',').Select(Guid.Parse).ToArray();
    query = query.Where(j => j.HospitalDepartments.Any(jj => jj.Units.Any(m => m.Devices.Any(w => selectedDeviceTypeIDs.Contains(w.DeviceTypeID)))));
}
```

Comment: why don't you use loop and check for equal data?

Comment: @Bharat Because that would require bringing the entire data set into memory and this looks like an Entity Framework query to me.

Comment: I usually test for not equal with a count of 0 which means everything matches.  Also use the Where((x,i) => .... Something like this Where((j,i) => (j.HospitalDepartments != selectedDeviceTypeIDs[i])).Count == 0

Comment: @Bharat, Thank you for your help :)
I need to check in database if the m => m.Devices has exactly the ids in selectedDeviceTypesIDs array the problem how to archive that since Devices.DeviceID is an object not array to check if it equal with selectedDeviceTypesIDs array

Comment: @DavidG,
Thank you for your help :)
I need to check in database if the m => m.Devices has exactly the ids in selectedDeviceTypesIDs array the problem how to archive that since Devices.DeviceID is an object not array to check if it equal with selectedDeviceTypesIDs array

Comment: is it completed?

Comment: Please don't post your solution in your question; that makes it very unclear what your question is. Instead, post the solution as an answer. Please read about [ask] and [answer] questions here.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

If you care about the Order of the items, use `SequenceEqual` extension method. This will return false, even if the collection has the items but in different order

```
m => m.Devices.Any(w => selectedDeviceTypeIDs.SequenceEqual(w.DeviceTypeID)
```

**Option 2:**

If you don't care about the order , use `All` extension method. This will return true, if the items in both collections are same irrespective of the order.

```
m => m.Devices.Any(w => selectedDeviceTypeIDs.All(w.DeviceTypeID.Contains)
```

Comment: Ranjith V.
Thank you so much for your help... i tried the above code... it gives me error because w.DeviceTypeID is a property not array to i can't compare it with selectedDeviceTypeIDs i think i need to get a list of w.DeviceTypeID and then compare it with  selectedDeviceTypeIDs... can you please help me to solve it 

[img](http://i.imgur.com/METdXiz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use *!.Except().Any()* to make sure **m.Devices** doesn't contains any **DeviceTypeID** not present in **selectedDeviceTypeIDs**

```
query = query.Where(j => j.HospitalDepartments.Any(jj => jj.Units
.Where(m => !m.Devices.Select(w => w.DeviceTypeID).Except(selectedDeviceTypeIDs).Any())));
```

Comment: Dear Innat3, 
I would thank you so much for your help and effort... I actually tried your code it didn't work... but maybe because we use where two times... i am sure if you took a look at the code again it will work, thank you again

Comment: Innat3 i am sorry if you are busy

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the `selectedDeviceTypeIDs` contains every device, and that every device contains `selectedDeviceTypeIDs`. You could use this:

```
query = query
.Where(j =>
    j.HospitalDepartments.Any(jj =>
        jj.Units.Any(m =>
            m.Devices.All(
                w => selectedDeviceTypeIDs.Contains(w.DeviceTypeID))
            &&
            selectedDeviceTypeIDs.All(
                g => m.Devices.Select(d => d.DeviceTypeID).Contains(g))
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: granit, I edited the question and solved it .Thank you so much for your help and effort :)

Comment: @Alex don't you get the same outcome by using the code in my answer and the one you wrote in your updated question?